# Very basic continuity question

Tags: calculus

Consider $$f(x)=\left\{\begin{matrix}
 1-x& 0<x<1/2\\ 
 0& x= 0,1/2 
\end{matrix}\right.$$

Is $f$ continuous at $0$ (or the other endpoints)? I tried verifying it with the epsilon delta argument when the limit is possible $1$ or $0$ and I got them both to agree...

My first conjecture was that if the limit was $1$ as x goes to $0$, I would choose $\delta = \epsilon$. If the limit was $0$ as $x\to0$, then I would choose $\delta = \epsilon+1$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\lim_{x\to 1/2^-}f(x)=\lim_{x\to 1/2^-}(1-x)=\frac{1}{2}\neq 0= f\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)\Longrightarrow \,f\,\,\text{is not continuous at}\,\,\frac{1}{2}$$

Try now to show something similar for $\,x=0\,$

Comment: That's what I thought too. What happened to the right limit?

Comment: First, there is none as the function isn't defined on the right of $\,1/2\,$, but even if it was: who cares? *The limit* exists iff both one sided limits exist, and the func. is continuous there iff the limit exists finitely and equals the function's value there, so if a one sided limit doesn't equal the function's value we're done, even if we're talking only about one sided continuity.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is no. This is because $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^+}f(x)\not=f(0)$

Comment: Is there even an $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}f(x)$

Comment: Yes there is. Note that the limit of f at a does not consider f(a)

Comment: Well, there is a *one-sided* limit at zero, not "the limit", as the function isn't defined on negative reals.

Comment: Yes you are right. I should have said this